# Merge 2 list in java based on matching key value

Tags: java, list, merge

I am looking to merge the list 1 and List 2 inorder to get the expected output as below.

*Both the lists are Java classes and also want to add to a new Java class on the expected structure.*

I have tried looping through List1 and List2 but in vain.

Also tried using lambda expression but could not get the expected output.

Will post the code that I tried.

Any help is highly appreciated.

List 1(juniorArea):

```
{
“One”: [
    "G13DA"
],
“Two”: [
    "G13AA",
    "G13AD"
]
}
```

List 2:

```
[
{
    "subgroupCode": "G13AA",
    "productGroup": [
        {
            "productCode": "G1A",
            "productDescription": “Two 1"
        },
        {
            "productCode": "G9B",
            "productDescription": “Two 2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "subgroupCode": "G13AD",
    "productGroup": [
        {
            "productCode": "G4A",
            "productDescription": “Two 3”
        },
        {
            "productCode": "G9C",
            "productDescription": “Two 4”
        }
    ]
},
{
    "subgroupCode": "G13DA",
    "productGroup": [
        {
            "productCode": "G5M",
            "productDescription": “One 1"
        },
        {
            "productCode": "G9M",
            "productDescription": “One 2"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
{
   "juniorArea": [   
{      
 "juniorAreaDescription": “One”,
          "mechandisingGroup": [
         {
                "productCode": "G5M",
                "productDescription": “One 1"
         },
         {
                "productCode": "G9M",
                "productDescription": “One 2"
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      "juniorAreaDescription": “Two”,
      "mechandisingGroup": [
         {
                "productCode": "G1A",
                "productDescription": “Two 1"
         },
         {
                "productCode": "G9B",
                "productDescription": “Two 2"
         },
     {
                "productCode": "G4A",
                "productDescription": “Two 3”
         },
         {
                "productCode": "G9C",
                "productDescription": “Two 4”
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Where are you currently struggling? Are these JSON objects you want to merge into another JSON object or are they Java classes? -> Please clarify with an [edit]

Comment: @Emraan Can you add classes for objects in your lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make use of Google's gson library to parse your json Strings and also create Additional Classes to hold the data for the same. Save your json String in Files to read the content and convert them to appropriate Objects.

The JSON Strings you have mentioned have error since you are using (“) at many places. Replace them with (") at all locations. This change is very important because if you don't do it you might get Exceptions or undesirable outputs.

Store your Json strings as follows:

List1.txt

```
{
"One": [
    "G13DA"
],
"Two": [
    "G13AA",
    "G13AD"
]
}
```

List2.txt

```
[
{
    "subgroupCode": "G13AA",
    "productGroup": [
        {
            "productCode": "G1A",
            "productDescription": "Two 1"
        },
        {
            "productCode": "G9B",
            "productDescription": "Two 2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "subgroupCode": "G13AD",
    "productGroup": [
        {
            "productCode": "G4A",
            "productDescription": "Two 3"
        },
        {
            "productCode": "G9C",
            "productDescription": "Two 4"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "subgroupCode": "G13DA",
    "productGroup": [
        {
            "productCode": "G5M",
            "productDescription": "One 1"
        },
        {
            "productCode": "G9M",
            "productDescription": "One 2"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

You will need to change the file paths of these two while Running the Program

Add the following classes

JuniorArea.class

```
public class JuniorArea {
    private String juniorAreaDescription;
    private List<MerchandisingGroup> mechandisingGroup;

    public String getJuniorAreaDescription() {
        return juniorAreaDescription;
    }
    public void setJuniorAreaDescription(String juniorAreaDescription) {
        this.juniorAreaDescription = juniorAreaDescription;
    }
    public List<MerchandisingGroup> getMechandisingGroup() {
        return mechandisingGroup;
    }
    public void setMechandisingGroup(List<MerchandisingGroup> mechandisingGroup) {
        this.mechandisingGroup = mechandisingGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JuniorArea [juniorAreaDescription=" + juniorAreaDescription + ", mechandisingGroup=" + mechandisingGroup
                + "]";
    }
}
```

JuniorAreaCollection.class

```
public class JuniorAreaCollection {
    private List<JuniorArea> juniorArea;

    public List<JuniorArea> getJuniorArea() {
        return juniorArea;
    }

    public void setJuniorArea(List<JuniorArea> juniorArea) {
        this.juniorArea = juniorArea;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JuniorAreaCollection [juniorArea=" + juniorArea + "]";
    }
}
```

MerchandisingGroup.class

```
public class MerchandisingGroup {
    private String productCode;
    private String productDescription;

    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }
    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }
    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }
    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MechandisingGroup [productCode=" + productCode + ", productDescription=" + productDescription + "]";
    }
}
```

Product.class

```
public class Product {
    private String subgroupCode;
    private List<ProductGroup> productGroup;

    public String getSubgroupCode() {
        return subgroupCode;
    }
    public void setSubgroupCode(String subgroupCode) {
        this.subgroupCode = subgroupCode;
    }
    public List<ProductGroup> getProductGroup() {
        return productGroup;
    }
    public void setProductGroup(List<ProductGroup> productGroup) {
        this.productGroup = productGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [subgroupCode=" + subgroupCode + ", productGroup=" + productGroup + "]";
    }
}
```

ProductGroup.class

```
public class ProductGroup {
    private String productCode;
    private String productDescription;

    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }
    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }
    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }
    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductGroup [productCode=" + productCode + ", productDescription=" + productDescription + "]";
    }
}
```

Finally run the follwing Main Class code, to check the output

```
public class MainRunner {
    // Use Path according to your file system
    private static String List1Path = "/List1.txt";

    // Use Path according to your file system
    private static String List2Path = "/List2.txt";

    public static void main(String...arg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        String List1Content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(List1Path)), "UTF-8");

        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        map = gson.fromJson(List1Content, new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {}.getType());

        System.out.println(map);

        String List2Content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(List2Path)), "UTF-8");

        List<Product> products = gson.fromJson(List2Content, new TypeToken<List<Product>>() {}.getType());

        System.out.println(products);

        List<JuniorArea> juniorAreas = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String s : map.keySet()) {
            JuniorArea juniorArea = new JuniorArea();

            juniorArea.setJuniorAreaDescription(s);

            List<MerchandisingGroup> merchandisingGroups = new ArrayList<>();

            List<String> subgroupCodes = map.get(s);

            for (String subgroupCode : subgroupCodes) {

                for (Product product : products) {

                    if (product.getSubgroupCode().equals(subgroupCode)) {
                        List<ProductGroup> productGroups = product.getProductGroup();

                        for (ProductGroup productGroup : productGroups) {
                            MerchandisingGroup merchandisingGroup = new MerchandisingGroup();

                            merchandisingGroup.setProductCode(productGroup.getProductCode());
                            merchandisingGroup.setProductDescription(productGroup.getProductDescription());

                            merchandisingGroups.add(merchandisingGroup);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            juniorArea.setMechandisingGroup(merchandisingGroups);

            juniorAreas.add(juniorArea);
        }

        JuniorAreaCollection collection = new JuniorAreaCollection();

        collection.setJuniorArea(juniorAreas);

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(collection));
    }
}
```

Output should be printed on your console

```
{
  "juniorArea": [
    {
      "juniorAreaDescription": "One",
      "mechandisingGroup": [
        {
          "productCode": "G5M",
          "productDescription": "One 1"
        },
        {
          "productCode": "G9M",
          "productDescription": "One 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "juniorAreaDescription": "Two",
      "mechandisingGroup": [
        {
          "productCode": "G1A",
          "productDescription": "Two 1"
        },
        {
          "productCode": "G9B",
          "productDescription": "Two 2"
        },
        {
          "productCode": "G4A",
          "productDescription": "Two 3"
        },
        {
          "productCode": "G9C",
          "productDescription": "Two 4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dinesh with some change in the data model as suggested, the solution works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Dinesh, The above part of code where we are merging 2 lists, is hitting performance. Can we have a logic to get it done using lambda expression, intersection of 2 lists?